# Excel get sum based on a unique value in two categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I want a formula that sums a column's value after getting rid of duplicates in two categories.
As the table shows below, first of all remove the duplations in both columns A and B and then sums the column INCOME

I tried to use a unique function

```
 =unique(range)
```

it's working fine if the duplications in one category, not two categories

[image]

hereafter removing  the duplications and I want to the result which is 10

[image]

Comment: your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:C7),0,3))
```

works for me in O365, assuming all three columns are duplicated as shown in your test data.

In fact you can simplify this if all the first two columns' entries are text because SUM will ignore them:

```
=SUM(UNIQUE(A2:C7))
```

In earlier versions of Excel, you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C7/COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,B2:B7,B2:B7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use a helper column, where you concatenate the two categories. You can use the `unique` function on that column.